# Custom angular validation directive doesn't work when I add ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material, angularjs-ng-click

My problem is so simple as weird. I have 2 dropdown (one for hours and the other one for minutes). I've made a validation using a directive (`zero-time-directive`) in Angular to validate that both of them cannot be 0 at the same time. The validation works and it's executed properly. However, if I add an `ng-click` function to the `md-option` tag, the directive stops being executed. Again, if I remove the `ng-click`, my validation directive is being executed again in both `md-option` tags.

I've tried to *wrapper* the `ng-click` inside `div` tags just in case the `md-option` doesn't accept the `ng-click` directive, but it doesn't work, the validation isn't executed. I think that the directive code isn't important because it works fine, but if you need to see it just let me know.

Dropdowns:

```
<md-input-container style="margin-left: 30px">
    <label>Hours*</label>
    <md-select ng-model="time.selectedHour" name="hours" zero-time-directive="{{time.selectedMinute}}">
        <md-option ng-repeat="hour in time.hours" value="{{hour}}" ng-click="setSelectedHour(hour)">
            {{hour}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div ng-messages="overtimeHoursForm.hours.$error">
        <div ng-message="noZero">Both time values cannot be zero.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container style="margin-left: 30px">
    <label>Minutes*</label>
    <md-select ng-model="time.selectedMinute" name="minutes" zero-time-directive="{{time.selectedHour}}">
        <md-option ng-repeat="minute in time.minutes" value="{{minute}}" ng-click="setSelectedMinute(minute)">
            {{minute}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div ng-messages="overtimeHoursForm.minutes.$error">
        <div ng-message="noZero">Both time values cannot be zero.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Controller:

```
function overtimeHoursController($scope, $http){

            $scope.time = {
                hours : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                minutes : [0, 15, 30, 45],
                selectedHour: 0,
                selectedMinute: 0
            }

            $scope.setSelectedHour = function(hour){

                $scope.time.selectedHour = hour;
            }

            $scope.setSelectedMinute = function(minute){

                $scope.time.selectedMinute = minute;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should work with `ng-change` rather than ng-click in `select`